# FastMember convert datagridview CurrentRow back to Objectt

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datarow, fastmember

I used this code to convert `IEnumerable<Register>` to `Datatable`, in order to use extended functionality in one `datagridview`.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data))
{
   table.Load(reader);
}
```

Now I need to get the object back, for example when clicking on the row.

```
private void dgRegisters_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0) return;
   var register = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Register;
}
```

I don't know how to get it back `var register`. It is always `null` because it is a `DataRowView`.

Answer (score 0):

The actual object was never stored; `ObjectReader` exposes a type as a data-reader, allowing consumers such as `DataTable` to read from it, but that doesn't mean you can trivially re-obtain the original object. However! You *could* try using Dapper, which has the ability to consume a data-reader and construct objects; you can create a reader to pass to Dapper via `DataTableReader`.

Comment: Thank you. If I could at least get '((DataRowView)senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).ObjectID' then I could get the same object from the initial list using the id.

Comment: @miguelmpn if that is a column, then sure: you can access that via the DataRowView API - presumably `theRow["ObjectID"]`

Comment: But ObjectID is unnacessible, I'll try another strategy, thank you